# upload picture to facebook wall API graph 3.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3

I was publishing pictures on Facebook wall of the current logged user using **API GRAPH 2.6**

Facebook announced this version will be deprecated and I want to use version **3.0**

One of the radical changes is that **publish_actions** permission is not supported any more.

How can I publish a picture for the version 3?

My pictures are stored in AWS S3 and the URL expire very frecuently so I need to upload the picture not the URL

In the following images you can see I was trying with *API GRAPH EXPLORER* **publish_action** permission do not exists but the error given by facebook is claming that I need that permission. Is very confusing
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24: _“If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this date, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.”_

Comment: _“My pictures are stored in AWS S3 and the URL expire very frecuently”_ - You could share links instead, that have the image set as thumbnail. You would just have to set it up so that when the URL for an image has expired, the new one gets returned the next time the scraper crawls that link.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. But, what you really mean with "links instead"?

Comment: What the changelog already links to - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing, to be used with URLs from your site that specify which image to show as thumbnail.